# Can't reset sign-in user's password

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In my app user could reset his password , i have tested that using my account , but my customer said got the Insufficient privileges to complete the operation error . I updated passwordProfile attribute  :

```
{ 
  "passwordProfile": { 
    "password":"" ,
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false 
  } 
}
```

The only difference is my account is admin account and customer's is not, does that the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you grant "Directory.AccessAsUser.All" delegated permission with microsoft graph so admin user could reset password , you could check the permission in access token by decode it using an online tool like [this one](http://jwt.calebb.net/) . That delegated permission allows an admin user to reset another user's password  , non- admin user can't rest his own password with Directory.AccessAsUser.All delegate permission .

please refer to [answer from @Dan Kershaw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44401918/5751404) for more details .