# Azure AD, change password

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm using the Admin user, with all the privileges but nonetheless, I cannot update the password of a user using the PATCH http call to `/users/USERID`.

Since this is a web api, I cannot use the data of the logged in user. The only available way to update the password is this Patch call, which used to work, but now no longer works (seems due to a AD security update?)

How do I force a certain password on one of my users then?

The code I get from AD is:

```
Authorization_RequestDenied
```

I'm already using the PATCH request at this URL:

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version
```

And I have given my application the required permission:

```
Directory.AccessAsUser.All
```

(In reality I gave all permissions to my application trying to enable the password reset)

Answer (score 0):

See [Insufficient privileges for password reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313884/insufficient-privileges-for-password-reset) - although it talks about Microsoft Graph API, I believe that the same applies to Azure AD Graph API. In short, there is no application permission that let you reset a user's password. But there is a workaround: you can assign an [AD role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles) to the service principal that represents your application.